# Avro schema: Cannot make fields optionable

Tags: java, json, avro

I have a field defined in my avro schema as follows.

```
                {
                  "name": "currency",
                  "type": ["null","string"],
                  "default": null
                },
```

I recieve some data as json as which doesnot contain field currency and it always throws this error.

```
Expected field name not found: currency
```

I use the following code to convert this to a generic object.

```
       DecoderFactory decoderFactory = new DecoderFactory();
        Decoder decoder = decoderFactory.jsonDecoder(schema, eventDto.toString());
        DatumReader<GenericData.Record> reader =
                new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
        GenericRecord genericRecord = reader.read(null, decoder);
```

Most of the stackoverflow and github answers suggest that what I did above should make the fields optional and should work fine. But this doesn't seem to work for me. Is there any way to solve this.

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: @SimranTea avro maven dependency. version 1.10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty common misunderstanding. The Java JSON decoder does not use defaults when a field is not found. This is because the JSON encoder would have included that field when creating the JSON and so the decoder expects the field to be there.

If you would like to add your support for having it use the defaults in the way you expect you can find a similar issue on [their tracker here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2890) and add a comment.

Comment: so null fields must be given explicitly?

Comment: If you are using the Avro JSON encoder, it will write out those null fields. The problem here is trying to decode arbitrary JSON or JSON that was produced with an older schema which the Java library doesn't currently do.